# How could router be "undefined" here in my Node app?

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();
```

I am debugging my Node app and `express` is defined, but after stepping over the `var router` line, `router` is still undefined, how could this happen?

Well here is all the code if you must:

```
var express = require('express')
//  , fancy_scripts = require('./fancy_scripts')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// New Code
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/sparks');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/fancy_scripts'));
app.use('/fancy_scripts',  express.static(__dirname + '/fancy_scripts'));


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

//var router = express.Router();
//
///* GET home page. */
//router.get('/', routes.index);
```

If were to guess the line `app.use(app.router);`

might be the culprit...?

Comment: put relevant code. how did u verify its undefined?

Comment: it is undefined when I debug it with eclipse

Comment: and above are only 2 lines you have?

Comment: no, I added the rest of the lines, I was trying to make it simpler, but perhaps the line "app.use(app.router);" is causing the problem.

Comment: What version of **Express** are you using? If you are using **Express 4**, a lot of what you have here is deprecated and/or won't work.